# Can't open all pages in ubuntu

Tags: pagestack

Recently I installed the latest evrsion of Ubuntu in my laptop. Version 17.04 Codename: Zesty. But the problem I am facing is that I cannot open many pages like www.google.com or any kind of search from google. But I can open Facebook or YouTube.

THanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu shouldn't have an issue such as this; I'd check something like a firewall or something on your network (or between your network & web) stopping you.

please provide more info - eg, browser used, and ideally some trace info, eg.

I'd suggest going to console (terminal) & using commands like

traceroute google.com

traceroute facebook.com

the second trace can be any site that works.

Providing this info could be too much info and reveal your location, ISP etc so you may want to 'filter' or only answer where it goes wrong.
fyi: traceroute is like a ping[=icmp.echo.request] but provides more detail

If no problem is obvious with network tools (such as traceroute), [install &] try a different browser